# why this ghostscript command is giving me error?

Tags: linux, ghostscript

I am just trying to change the  orientation of a file before piping it to lp since the -o option is not working :

```
gs -sDEVICE=pxlcolor -sOutputFile="\|lp -dprintername" -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice" -f "inputfile"
```

gives :

```
    GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)
Copyright (C) 2009 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefined in This
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1862   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   1845   1   3   %oparray_pop   1739   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1149/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:70/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 5
GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

even this gives similar error :

```
gs -sDEVICE=pxlmono -sOutputFile=/dev/stdout -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice" -f "test"
```

Comment: Maybe `gs -q ...` might help; the error suggests that the default startup output of gs (`This...`) is piped to the device as well. Or there is something wrong with your input file (look at the start of it).